# Mysql : Displaying number of rows for every table in a given database

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to display number of rows for every table in a given database **with a single command**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the information_schema:

```
select table_schema database, table_name, table_rows rowcount
       from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'DATABASE_TO_LOOK_UP'
and engine = 'MYISAM';
```

Afaik only for MyISAM-tables an exact rowcount is stored in the information_schema tables. If you use the SQL above for INNODB-tables, the rowcount displayed will be an approximation.